# vb.net program cannot connect to wampserver

Tags: mysql, vb.net, networking, wampserver

I have a vb.net program that uses mysql as its database. And it works when the computer has wampservr installed. But the program gets an unhandled exception error when the computer where its running does not have a wampserver. The only thing that is installed in it is the mysql connector net. How do I make it work. I just want the two programs to access the same mysql database. 
I already opened port 20 by configuring firewall. Both in TCP and UDP. What do I do? Do I have to tweak the codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the machine that you dont have wampserver installed, do you have MySql installed by itself?
If I understand your question correctly, sounds like its having trouble connecting to the database because its not there.

Comment: yeah, that's right, that's why I want to put the mysql database on the network. But I just don't know how.